# URLs get invalid while deploying ASP.NET MVC application from development server to production server

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this question is old but I am trying to understand the logic behind.
What am I doing?

I have created an ASP.NET MVC app and I have successfully deployed it on IIS  server.

The problem?

When I deploy all the ajax calls get invalid because of appname in the url:

```
hostname.com/{appname}/Home/Ajaxcall
```

in my ajax calls.

I am using relative urls like

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/CustomerAccount/Ajaxcreateinvoicesave',
        type: 'Post',
        data: data,
        success: function (res) {
            datatable.fnDraw();
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
```

but to runs this on server I have to write urls like

```
 url: '{appname}/Customeraccount/ajaxcreateinvoicesave'
```

What I want/want to understand?

How shared hosting or cloud hosting does not require this url rewriting. They work fine there without any modification.

Also if there any way to directly point Index without using appname in url 
e.g

```
domain.com/{appname}/home/index
```

to

```
domain.com/home/index
```

in iis (in production environment)

Comment: `url: '/CustomerAccount/Ajaxcreateinvoicesave',` works fine (although you should always be using `url: '@Url.Action("Ajaxcreateinvoicesave", "CustomerAccount")',` to generate your urls

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("Ajaxcreateinvoicesave")',` try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using string literal urls, what you need it to `Url.Action` helper method for generating the  proper relative urls so that you don't face the problem which you have stated above, you can change your urls to be generated via the method  mentioned above like:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Ajaxcreateinvoicesave","CustomerAccount")'
```

If your all js is in external files  then you will need to use `data-` attribute in html like:

```
<input type="button" id="btnId" 
       data-url="@Url.Action("Ajaxcreateinvoicesave","CustomerAccount")" />
```

and then in the client side code you would need to capture the url to  send ajax call.

Comment: Note that `@Url.Action` and other `UrlHelper` based methods use *routing* to determine what the URL is. A great feature of routing is that it will serve as the *single place* in the application where all of the URLs exist, provided it is not bypassed by hard coding the URLs into the views and controllers. It also automatically adjusts all of those URLs when there is an `{appname}` added by the server configuration.

Comment: what about css url property @Ehsan

Comment: @AhsanMuzafar you should use `Url.Contentt` method for those like: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript></script>"` and likwise for css